# Angular speed of a line segment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity

> The length of line segment joining P and Q is constant and equal to 10m. The velocities of P and Q are in directions inclined at angles 30 and 60 respectively with PQ . If the speed of P is 90m/s , what is the angular speed of PQ expressed in rads
> [image]

So, apparently the angular velocity of PQ in this case is defined as:

$$ \omega = \frac{v\sin \beta - u \sin \alpha}{l}$$

This expression I can't understand.

I understand how to define angular velocity for a point particle, where it is given as $ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ but how do you extend this definition for a whole line segment and arrive at the expression written above? Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Is PQ the axis of rotation?

Comment: $\overrightarrow{\omega }=\dfrac{\overrightarrow{v}\times \overrightarrow{r}}{\overrightarrow{r}\cdot \overrightarrow{r}}$

Comment: @mmesser314 I don't think so, they just told it's a line segment as in quoted text

Comment: @Eli fair but how do I apply that here

Comment: $\overrightarrow{v}=v\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \left( \beta \right)  \\
\sin \left( \beta \right)  \\
0
\end{pmatrix},\overrightarrow{r}=\begin{pmatrix}
l \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ I have problem with the minus sign?

Comment: just magnitude is ok @Eli

Comment: from the above equation you obtain $\dfrac{v\sin \left( \beta \right) }{l}$ is this correct?

Comment: That exp for omega you've written is wrong, I've written the correct / intended answer in the post @Eli

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but here goes...

1. Put everything in the reference frame of $P$.
2. The vertical component of the velocity of $P$ is $u \sin \alpha$, and the vertical component of the velocity of $Q$ is $v \sin \beta$.  So the relative velocity of $Q$ (in the reference frame of $P$) is $v \sin \beta - u \sin \alpha$.
3. The horizontal component of velocity may be ignored because $PQ$ doesn't change.  (I am slightly unsure on this point, but at the instant shown in the drawing I think this is true).
4. The angular velocity of $Q$ about $P$ is then
   $$\omega = \frac{velocity}{radial\,distance\,from\,P} = \frac{v \sin \beta - u \sin \alpha}{l}$$

I suspect this is what was intended.